# Get the hours differance fromtwo dates times in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to sucstract hours from datetime.
I tried with setHours and AddHours and both of the times in the debugger i see "undefined".
This is my function, everyting that i marked is things that i tried:

```
     function timeLine(hours) {
        var dt = new Date();
        debugger;
        //var calculatedDateTime = dt.setHours(dt.setHours() - (hours));
        //var calculatedDateTime = dt.setHours(hours);
        //var calculatedDateTime = dt.(hours);
        //var calculatedDateTime = dt.AddHours(dt.AddHours() - (hours));;
        $("#tblAlarms").find("tr").each(function (index) {
            if (index === 0) return;
            var filterColumn = $(this).find("td").eq(4);
            if (Date.parse(filterColumn) > calculatedDateTime)
                $(this).show();
            else
                $(this).hide();
        }
```

This is where i set the hours:
onclick="timeLine(-12)">12

Can someone help me please?

Comment: Where is the "C#" or ".NET" code? Please use correct tags.

Comment: Where is c# ? It is jquery and javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
(dateNow - datePast) / 3600000
```

This will give you the number of hours.

and

```
new Date(date - hours * 3600000)
```

will substract an amount of hours from your date and give you the new date.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the AddHours() to subtract the hours from Date by passing negative values.

DateTime dt = dt.AddHours(-6);

Answer (score 0):

```
var d = new Date();
var hours = 12;
d.setHours(d.getHours() - hours);
alert(d);
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7r1ybxdu/)

Answer (score 0):

Use [moment](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/) for any date/time calculations:

Example:

```
moment(date1).diff(date2,'minutes');
moment(date1).diff(date2,'days');
```